# What creational pattern I should use?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, creation-pattern

My program have two classes; both derive from same base class.

```
class A : MyBase
{
    internal A(InitVal initVal)
}

class B : MyBase
{
    internal B(InitVal initVal)
}
```

`InitVal` is another class which is injected through constructor. This class is for internal usage. Due to internal constructor, user cannot create instance of class `A` and `B` directly. Instead, I created method which creates these objects.

```
class Initiator
{
    InitVal initVal;

    public T CreateObject<T>(ObjectInstance objectInstance) where T : MyBase
    {
        MyBase myBase = null;
        switch(objectInstance)
        {
            case ObjectInstance.A:
                myBase = new A(initVal);
                break;
            case ObjectInstance.B:
                myBase = new B(initVal);
                break;
        }
        return (T)myBase;
    }
    ...
}
```

`ObjectInstance` is enum in above code.

This works without problem but I am sure you have never seen such ugly code earlier.

Please suggest creational pattern I should use. I want to remove `ObjectInstance` enum without changing functionality. It will cleanup much.

I tried **Creational Patterns** mentioned on [dotfactory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns).
`Factory Method` and `Abstract Factory` does not look proper in this case.

My code even though look ugly, it is very simple to read and understand. I tried implementing patterns mentioned above which increases code complexity. So this is also my criteria while choosing answer.

I cannot change anything in code except `Initiator` class. All other classes are not accessible to me for edit.

**Edit 1: Why above code is ugly in my view**

1) While calling `CreateObject` method, user have to specify type of the object twice.

```
A a = initiator.CreateObject<A>(ObjectInstance.A);
```

First for `T` generic value and second to enum value.
I want to avoid this.

2) As user has to specify type of object twice, there are chances of mistake.

```
A a = initiator.CreateObject<A>(ObjectInstance.B);
```

In above code, enum value and generic value are different.
This is not allowed and will be a problem.
With my code, I cannot avoid this.

That is why; I am looking for pattern that suits my case without increasing complexity.

If I remove necessity of enum somehow, code will be lot better.
If I can change signature of `CreateObject` to following, it will be lot better.

```
public T CreateObject<T>() where T : MyBase
```

But, I am not sure how I will implement this method to create proper instances.

Comment: If you cannot change `A` or `B`, then people can still create instances of `A` and/or `B`. Then why bother with the whole `Initiator` class?

Comment: I would make the constructor internal if you don't want consumers of your API to instantiate the classes

Comment: Your code isn´t that ugly and it is exactly what a factory-method does: it creates instances of a type based on some distinct value, in your case en enum. You could also do this via a config-file to not have to change your source-code if a new class is added. Only *really* uggly thing is your indentation.

Comment: One issue with your current `Initiator` class is that users now have to construct an instance of the `Initiator`, and that `initVal` somehow has to be set. How is the field set?

Comment: other way, a bit cleaner would be to simply have 2 methods to create A or B and 3rd party method would choose one of them. Or implement it as one method and decide on type by specifying generic type. Otherwise its jsut a Factory method and it seems fine. PS. Make the initiator static and initVal an argument most likely :P

Comment: still not even close to correct one I'd say :D

Comment: @Maarten: Yes; user have to create instance of `Initiator` which is fine. It also provides some other services to user. About `initVal`, it is set properly in other part of code. That is not a problem.

Comment: How / where do you decide if you it is an A or a B which you want? Will the type vary between different calls during one program execution?

Comment: the call would look like A myInstance = initiator.CreateObject<A>();
 you can achieve that in several ways, best is with specifying generic constraint of parameterless constructor and constructing new object as var t = new T(); provide this constructor as intenal one and then simply fill all its properties. Or use reflection

Comment: @mikus Regarding the generic method: the generic type would have to be constrained to either type `A` or `B`, and that is something you cannot do with generic constraints.

Comment: what do you mean? the method is already a generic, but it doesnt make much use of it yet :P check the answer

Comment: Why are you not just returning `MyBase` - are there some methods only in the derived classes that you need to call? A the moment, without any context about how you intend to use this, it looks like an antipattern.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Yes, there are methods in derived classes that user will need to call.

Comment: Well since you need to know the concrete type at call time AND for the returned value, I'd write a separate strongly-typed and nongeneric factory method for each type you want to create, called `CreateA()`, `CreateB()` etc.

Comment: so then user already knows the desired class type while calling, therefore needs to specify it both as enum and as generic type, pretty error prone. Seems that my answer should solve this issue. Ort simply write separate methods as I suggested before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like you are getting any advantage from trying to make this generic. You needs to know the concrete type of the returned value at the call site.

Therefore why not keep things simple and just do this?

```
public class Initiator
{
    InitVal initVal;

    public A CreateA()
    {
        return new A(initVal);
    }

    public B CreateB()
    {
        return new B(initVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MatthewWatson, its not really a factory method, as factory method by definition decides on the type, those don't decide on anything, simply construct always the same type. But well, who cares about the naming if it works

Answer (score 1):

As you specified the method as generic one, I expect you might actually know the type you want to get already during the compilation time.. so I'd go for something like this:

```
class Initiator
{ 
    public T CreateObject<T>(ObjectInstance objectInstance) where T : MyBase, new()
    {
        T newInstance = new T();
        newInstance.Value = initVal;

        return newInstance;
    }
...
}
```

now you can call it as:

```
A myAInstance = initiator.CreateObject<A>();
MyBase myAInstance = initiator.CreateObject<A>();   //this also works
```

To make it work you need to specify an internal **parameterless constructor** in your classes and specify *interface* for the Value property or whatever you would set now in your current constructor.

```
class MyBase{
    InitVal Value { get; set;}       //this allows construction of the object with parameterless constructor
    ...
}
```

This is not only cleaner and shorter, but also less error prone, as you dont need to edit both enum and method body every time new type is added. It gives less flexibility for child-type specific logic, though.

NOTE: If you really want to have constructor with parameters as you have now you still can go for this approach but you'd need to use **reflection** (check Activator) or lambdas.

Of course this makes only sense if you can decide on the type during compilation time or you if you just want to delegate this decition  to a 3rd party library, eg:

```
switch(chosenType){
case ObjectInstance.A:
    instance = initiator.CreateObject<A>();
    ...
```

Otherwise, simply leave it as it is, its a FactoryMethod pattern more or less and it does the job. Just that the generic parameter in it... seems to be quite useless then. I would remove it and change return type to MyBase, as user won't be able to specify T anyway.

One last option is to simply create a **separate method for each type**, this is clean, flexible, gives a lot of options for customization, but sucks if you need to repeat a lot of shared logic and you need to add a new one for each next type. Simply:

```
A CreateObjectA(InitVal initValue){
     return new A(initValue);
}
B CreateObjectB(InitVal initValue){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem with your code is the enum, which is unnecessary, because `typeof(T)` already gives you the appropriate type:

```
class Initiator
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<MyBase>> _dict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<MyBase>>();

    internal Initiator(InitVal initVal)
    {
        // initialize your "service locator".
        // it's cool that different types can have different constructors,
        // and people who call CreateObject don't need to know this.
        _dict[typeof(A)] = (Func<MyBase>)(() => new A(initVal));
        _dict[typeof(B)] = (Func<MyBase>)(() => new B(initVal, someOtherStuff));
    }

    public T CreateObject<T>() where T : MyBase
    {
        var ctor = _dict[typeof(T)];
        return (T)ctor();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't know the type, you can pass the enum, but then the return type should be an interface/base class (preferably interface):

```
// this is more likely, you probably don't need a generic method
public IMyBase CreateObject(ObjectInstance objectInstance)
{
    // the dictionary would map enum value to Func<IMyBase>, of course
    var ctor = _dict[objectInstance];
    return ctor();
}
```

And now you have a simple "poor man's" DI class called `Initiator`, so I wonder if your DI framework (the one which injected `InitVal`) can also inject `A` and `B` instances. Which is probably true, since DI purists will tell you there is no place for factories and the `new` keyword in your code.

**Btw, `ObjectInstance` is a really, really bad name for an enum.**

Answer (score 0):

I did it in following way:

```
class A : IMyType
{
    internal A(InitVal initVal)
}

class B : IMyType
{
    internal B(InitVal initVal)
}

class Initiator
{
    InitVal initVal = .....;

    public T CreateObject<T>() where T : IMyType
    {
        IMyType myType = null;
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(A))
            myType = new A(initVal);
        else if(typeof(T) == typeof(B))
            myType = new B(initVal);
        else
            throw new MyException("Type is not configured.");
        return (T)myType;
    }
    ...
}
```

This resolves the problems I mentioned in my question. But, it creates new problem. **This violates open-close principle of SOLID**. Last `else` block handles the manual mistake if any. Anyway, it just works for my specific case; **not recommended** generally.